# How do I edit report issue page field in mantis

Tags: php, mantis

I'm a beginner in mantis, please help me to solve

I want to edit some field in report issue page

1. set default value in category column while reporter report issue
2. set platform/OS/OS version in combo box and set default value, like Windows/Linux in OS

[report issue page-before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpQhT.png)

[report issue page - after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUQBq.png)

please help

Comment: I found a way to solve Q2 but not perfect  
go Manage -> Manage Global Profiles and add Profile  
set it done. The report issues page will show a combo box and the value in which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login as Administrator
2. Select "Manage" from the main menu.
3. Select "Manage Custom Fields" from the management menu.
4. In case of edit, click on the name of an existing custom field to edit its information.
5. In case of adding a new one, enter the name of the new custom field then click "New Custom Field".

Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, Is there any way that I could edit the php file to edit exist column instead of adding new column?

Comment: Use custom_strings_inc.php

if ( $g_active_language === 'english' ) {
$s_summary = 'Title';
}


Look in lang/strings_english.txt for all text with summary, and place them ( translate ) in custom_strings_inc.php.

You can also translate other languages

if ( $g_active_language === 'english' ) {
$s_summary = 'Samenvatting';
}

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, but this is not the ideal request. I've put the image in my question, sorry for the ambiguous description